# Set absolute page size without scaling in asymptote

Tags: paper-size, asymptote

*This is not the first time trying to solve this problem, which is why I'm writing a self-answered question, after spending another hour to re-discover a solution.*

How do I force Asymptote to output a PDF or EPS with a given exact page size, regardless of what graphical elements are drawn into it and without scaling the content?

Comment: Your contribution is appreciated, but would be more helpful if you could explain how you need more than the `size(width, height)` command, e.g., `size(50mm, 10mm);`

Comment: @CharlesStaats AIFCT, `size()` does not prevent the output page to be smaller than requested. Also, its documentation talks about scaling of the graphic, which I do not want to happen.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
// Requested page boundaries.
pair page_min = (0mm, 0mm);
pair page_max = (50mm, 10mm);

// Label sticking out of the requested frame.
label("Lorem ipsum", (0, 0), E);

// Line, shorter in one direction of the frame, longer in the other.
draw((0mm, 0mm) -- (20mm, 20mm), 1mm + black);

// Clip the elements in the current picture. Prevents the page from being enlarged and needs to be called after all drawing commands.
clip(box(page_min, page_max));

// Set the page size. Prevents the page from being shrunken.
fixedscaling(page_min, page_max);
```